# Как спарсить только текст поста вк

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

я написал код спарсил 1(последнюю запись)
дальше хочу чтобы выводило текст но

```
import requests

def parser():
    token = "<access_token>"
    version = 5.131
    domain = "fmmt_sstu"
    count = 1

    response = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get',

                            params = {
                                'access_token' : token,
                                'v': version,
                                'domain': domain,
                                'count': count
                            }

                            )

    data = response.json()['response']['items']['text']
    print(data)
parser()
```

так не работает выдает ошибку
Рабочий код (без вывода текста(лишняя информация ненужна))

```
import requests


def parser():
    token = "<access_token>"
    version = 5.131
    domain = "fmmt_sstu"
    count = 1

    response = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get',

                            params = {
                                'access_token' : token,
                                'v': version,
                                'domain': domain,
                                'count': count
                            }

                            )

    data = response.json()['response']['items']
    print(data)
parser()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Несмотря на то, что Вы запрашивает одну запись, Вам возвращается **список** `items`. Чтобы получить доступ к объекту записи, обратитесь по индексу к первому элементу списка.

***Пример:***

```py
# ...
data = response.json()['response']['items'][0]['text']
# ...
```

***stdout:***

```html
Собрание со студентами 1 курса по вопросу реализации дисциплины "Физическая культура и спорт". Обязательно к посещению! 

На этом собрании вы узнаете ответы на следующие вопросы:
Как легко и полезно для здоровья получить зачет по физре?
Какие секции студент может посещать? 
Какие медицинские справки для занятия физрой? 
И все другие, интересующие тебя вопросы.

Дата проведения - 3 сентября 
Время проведения - 8:00
Место проведения - аудитория №36, корпус №3 СамГТУ

Явка обязательна!
```